# Configuration Slicing plugin to discard old builds and artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use Configuration Slicing plugin to discard build and artifacts for a lot of different jobs in jenkins. However, I'm not exactly sure on how to configure it.

[Discard Old Builds Slicer - Days to keep artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBR3G.png)

The Item Names I understand would be the list of jobs we would like to discard the builds for. The configured value section has disabled by default. Should I make it enabled?

Where should I specify the #Days to Keep the artifacts? Is it in the dialogue box below?

Can anyone please provide examples on how to configure this? I'm trying to configure this in a live environment. I would like to be sure before making any changes.

Tia,
Lakshmi

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. 
Try to fill in the number of days for which you want to see the older builds where it says (Disabled) by default. Fill in the name of the jobs you want to apply the rule to under Item Names. Then Save.
For the changes to reflect you need to run the jobs once. This worked for me.
You can also use the Discard Old Builds Slicer - Max # of builds to keep with artifacts if you want to restrict to a certain number of builds. Configure it the same way.

Please see the screenshot attached.
[Screenshot of Discard Old Builds Slicer - Days to keep artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ypfz.png)